# Magento Display out of stock products not working

Tags: php, magento

I wasted more than 5 hours trying to figure out why I can't see Out of stock products in the home page of my Magento. I'm using SM Tablisting and, before you ask, yes, it supports Out of stock products.

I know the story. Configuration > Inventory > Display out of stock products > Yes > Save & Re-index. Too bad that I still can't see Out of stock products in my home page.

I debugged the entire List.php file of my Magento and it seems the problem is in the core of Magento. Let me explain. I'm using Inventory functionalities and when a product is not in stock (quantity = 0) Magento puts "Availability" equal to "Not available". For obvious reasons I can't put "Available" when quanitity is zero and the array of products in home page comes just with "Available" products. So what's the solution? I really don't get the point of setting Display out of stock products > Yes.

I update my message with the code that my website is using to show products in home page:

```
class Sm_Tablisting_Block_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected $_config = null;
    protected $products_viewed = null;
public function __construct($attributes = array()){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_config = Mage::helper('tablisting/data')->get($attributes);
}

public function getConfig($name=null, $value=null){
    if (is_null($this->_config)){
        $this->_config = Mage::helper('tablisting/data')->get(null);
    }
    if (!is_null($name) && !empty($name)){
        $valueRet = isset($this->_config[$name]) ? $this->_config[$name] : $value;
        return $valueRet;
    }
    return $this->_config;
}

public function setConfig($name=null, $value=null){
    if (is_null($this->_config)) $this->getConfig();
    if (is_array($name)){
        Mage::log($name);
        $this->_config = array_merge($this->_config, $name);
        return;
    }
    if (!empty($name)){
        $this->_config[$name] = $value;
    }
    return true;
}

public function getConfigObject(){
    return (object)$this->getConfig();
}


public function generateHash(){
    $config = $this->getConfig();
    $this->hash = md5( serialize($config) );
    return $this->hash;
}

public function _beforeHtml(){
    $this->generateHash();
}

protected function _toHtml(){
    if(!$this->getConfig('isenabled')) return;
    $is_ajax = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('is_ajax');
    if( $is_ajax ){
        $cat_id    = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('tab_cat_id');
        $order_id  = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $type      = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('data_type');
        if( $type == 'order' ){
            $child_items = $this->getProductsOrder($order_id);
        } else {
            $child_items = $this->getProducts($cat_id);
        }
        $template_file = 'sm/tablisting/default_items.phtml';
    }else{
        $template_file = 'sm/tablisting/default.phtml';
    }
    $this->setTemplate($template_file);
    return parent::_toHtml();
}

public function getStoreId(){
    if (is_null($this->_storeId)){
        $this->_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    }
    return $this->_storeId;
}
public function setStoreId($storeId=null){
    $this->_storeId = $storeId;
}   

protected function getProductCollection(){
    $collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $visibility = array(
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
            Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
    );
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility);
    // add price data
    $collection->addPriceData();
    $this->_addViewsCount($collection);
    $this->_addReviewsCount($collection);
    $this->_addOrderedCount($collection);
    return $collection;
}

public function setProductCollection($collection=null){
    $this->_productCollection = $collection;
}   

public function getTotal(){
    if ($this->getConfig('product_category')==''){
        return;
    }
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    $category_collection->setStoreId($storeId);
    $category_collection->addIsActiveFilter();
    $category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $category_collection->addIdFilter( $this->getConfig('product_category') );
    $list = array();
    $items = array();
    $result = array();
    foreach ($category_collection as $category) {
        $category_obj       = new stdClass();
        $category_obj->id       = $category->getId();
        // category products
        $product_collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $product_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $product_collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);

        // select active & visible in Catalog products
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($product_collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($product_collection);

        foreach ($product_collection as $product){
            $product_obj = new stdClass();
            $product_obj->id = $product->getId();
            $stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
            $stock = $product->getStockItem();
            $status = $stock->getIsInStock();
            if( $stocklevel > 0 && $status == '1' ){
                $items[$product_obj->id] = $product_obj;
            }

        }
        $result = $items;
    }
    return $result;
}

public function getCategory(){
    $list = array();
    $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    $is_ajax = $params['is_ajax'];
    $cat_id = $params['tab_cat_id'];
    $orderid = $this->_config['product_order_by'];      
    $total = count($this->getTotal());
    //var_dump($total);
    $all = new stdClass();
    $all->id   = '*';
    $all->count = $total;
    $all->title = 'All Product';
    $all->sel   = 'sel';
    $all->orderid   = $orderid;
    $all->child = $this->getProducts();
    if ( $is_ajax ){
        $all->child = $this->getProducts('*');
    }
    array_unshift($list, $all);

    if ( $this->getConfig('product_category')=='' ){
        return array();
    }

    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    $category_collection->setStoreId($storeId);
    $category_collection->addIsActiveFilter();
    $category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $category_collection->addIdFilter( $this->getConfig('product_category') );

    foreach ($category_collection as $category) {
        $items = array();
        $category_obj       = new stdClass();
        $category_obj->id   = $category->getId();
        $category_obj->title = $category->getName();
        $category_obj->link     = $category->getUrl();
        $product_collection     = $category->getProductCollection();
        foreach( $product_collection as $product ){
            $product_obj = new stdClass();
            $product_obj->id = $product->getId();
            $stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
            $stock = $product->getStockItem();
            $status = $stock->getIsInStock();
            if( $stocklevel > 0 && $status == '1' ){
                $items[$product_obj->id] = $product_obj;
            }                   
        }
        $category_obj->count    = count($items);    
        $category_obj->orderid   = $orderid;
        if ( $is_ajax ){
            $category_obj->child    = $this->getProducts($cat_id);
        }
        $list[]= $category_obj;
    }
    return $list;
}

public function getProducts($cat_id ){
    $collection = $this->getProductCollection();
    $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    $is_ajax = $params['is_ajax'];
    $cat_id = $params['tab_cat_id'];
    $cat_config = $params['config_categoryid'];
    $items = array();
    $this->addReviewSummaryTemplate('sm', 'sm/tablisting/summary.phtml');
    $items = array();
    if ( Mage::registry('current_category') ){
        //is category view page.
        $current_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        $current_category_id = $current_category->getId();
        $product_ids = $current_category->getProductCollection()->getAllIds();
        $collection->addIdFilter($product_ids);
        $category_ids = array();
    } else {
        if( $is_ajax ){
            if( $cat_id != '*' ){
                $category_ids = preg_split("/[,\s\D]+/", $cat_id);
            } else {
                $category_ids = preg_split("/[,\s\D]+/", $cat_config);
            }
        } else {
            $category_ids = preg_split("/[,\s\D]+/", $this->_config['product_category']);
        }
        if (is_array($category_ids)){
            foreach ($category_ids as $i => $id) {
                if (!is_numeric($id)){
                    unset($category_ids[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (isset($category_ids) && count($category_ids)>0) $this->_addCategoryFilter($collection, $category_ids);
    // Sort products in collection
    $dir = strtolower( $this->_config['product_order_dir'] );
    if (!in_array($dir, array('asc', 'desc'))){
        $dir = 'asc';
    }

    $attribute_to_sort = $this->_config['product_order_by'];
    switch ($attribute_to_sort){
        case 'name':
        case 'created_at':
        case 'price':
            $collection->addAttributeToSort($attribute_to_sort, $dir);
            break;
        case 'position':
            break;
        case 'random':
            $collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
            break;
        case 'top_rating':
            $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_rating_summary desc');
            break;
        case 'most_reviewed':
            $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_reviews_count desc');
            break;
        case 'most_viewed':
            $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_views_count desc');
            break;
        case 'best_sales':
            $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_ordered_count desc');
            break;
    }

    if( $is_ajax ){
        $product_limitation = intval(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('ajax_tablisting_start'));
        $collection->getSelect()->limit( $this->_config['product_limitation'], $product_limitation );
    } else {
        $product_limitation = intval($this->_config['product_limitation']);
        if ( $product_limitation > 0 ){
            $collection->setPageSize($product_limitation);
        }
    }
    $maxtitle = $this->getConfig('item_title_max_characs',-1);
    foreach( $collection as $k => $product ) {
        $product_obj = new stdClass();
        $product_obj->id = $product->getId();

        if ( $maxtitle  > 0 ){
            $product_obj->title = Mage::helper('tablisting/data')->truncate($product->getName(), $maxtitle, '');
        } else {
            $product_obj->title = $product->getName();
        }
        $description = $product->getShortDescription();
        if ( (int)$this->getConfig('item_description_striptags') == 1 ){
            $keep_tags = $this->getConfig('item_description_keeptags', '');
            $keep_tags = str_replace(array(' '), array(''), $keep_tags);
            $tmp_desc = strip_tags($description ,$keep_tags );
            $product_obj->description = $tmp_desc;
        } else {
            $product_obj->description = $description;
        }
        if (($maxchars=$this->getConfig('item_desc_max_characs',-1))>0){
            $product_obj->description = Mage::helper('tablisting/data')->truncate($product_obj->description, $maxchars, '');
        }
        $product_obj->image = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize($this->getConfig('item_image_width'), $this->getConfig('item_image_height'));
        $product_obj->link = $product->getProductUrl();
        $product_obj->price_html = $this->getPriceHtml($product, true);
        $product_obj->review_html = $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, 'sm', true);
        $product_obj->orderid =  $attribute_to_sort;
        $stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
        $stock = $product->getStockItem();
        $status = $stock->getIsInStock();
        if( $stocklevel > 0 && $status == '1' ){
            $items[$product_obj->id] = $product_obj;
        }
        //$items[$product_obj->id] = $product_obj;
    }
    return $items;
}   

public function getCategoryOrder(){
    $total = count($this->getTotal());
    $order_by = preg_split("/\,/", $this->_config['order_tab']);
    $items = array();
    while( count($order_by) ){
        $item = array();
        $item = trim(array_shift($order_by));
        array_push($items, $item);
    }

    $order_attr  = Mage::getModel('tablisting/system_config_source_orderBy');
    $order_label = $order_attr->toOptionArray(true);

    $list = array();
    $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    if( $params ){
        $is_ajax = $params['is_ajax'];
        $cat_id = $params['tab_cat_id'];
        $order_id = $params['order_id'];
    }else{
        $is_ajax = "";
        $cat_id = "";
        $order_id = "";
    }           
    $total = count($this->getTotal());
    if ( $this->getConfig('product_category')=='' ){
        return array();
    }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $items as $category ) { $i++;
        $category_obj        = new stdClass();
        foreach ($order_label as $titel){
            if ( $category == $titel['value'] ){
                $category_obj->title = $titel['label'];
            }
        }
        $category_obj->id    = $category;
        $category_obj->orderid  = $category;
        $category_obj->count = $total;
        if ( $is_ajax ){
            $category_obj->child    = $this->getProductsOrder($order_id);
        }
        if( $i== 1 ){
            $category_obj->child    = $this->getProductsOrder($order_id);
            $category_obj->id       = $items['0'];
            $category_obj->sel      = 'sel';
            $category_obj->orderid  = $items['0'];
        }
        $list[]= $category_obj;
    }
    return $list;
}

public function getProductsOrder($order_id){
    $collection = $this->getProductCollection();
    $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
    if( $params ){
        $is_ajax = $params['is_ajax'];
        $cat_id = $params['tab_cat_id'];
        $order_id = $params['order_id'];
        $cat_config = $params['config_categoryid']; 
    }else{
        $is_ajax = "";
        $cat_id = "";
        $order_id = "";
        $cat_config = "";
    }
    $order_by = preg_split("/\,/", $this->_config['order_tab']);
    $cat = array();
    while( count($order_by) ){
        $item = array();
        $item = trim(array_shift($order_by));
        array_push($cat, $item);
    }
    $items = array();
    $this->addReviewSummaryTemplate('sm', 'sm/tablisting/summary.phtml');
    $items = array();
    if ( Mage::registry('current_category') ){
        //is category view page.
        $current_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        $current_category_id = $current_category->getId();
        $product_ids = $current_category->getProductCollection()->getAllIds();
        $collection->addIdFilter($product_ids);
        $category_ids = array();
    } else {
        if( $is_ajax ){
            $category_ids = preg_split("/[,\s\D]+/", $cat_config);
        } else {
            $category_ids = preg_split("/[,\s\D]+/", $this->_config['product_category']);
        }
        if (is_array($category_ids)){
            foreach ($category_ids as $i => $id) {
                if (!is_numeric($id)){
                    unset($category_ids[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (isset($category_ids) && count($category_ids)>0) $this->_addCategoryFilter($collection, $category_ids);

    // Sort products in collection
    $dir = strtolower( $this->_config['product_order_dir'] );
    if (!in_array($dir, array('asc', 'desc'))){
        $dir = 'asc';
    }

    if( $is_ajax ){
        $attribute_to_sort = $order_id;
        switch ($attribute_to_sort){
            case 'name':
            case 'created_at':
            case 'price':
                $collection->addAttributeToSort($attribute_to_sort, $dir);
                break;
            case 'position':
                break;
            case 'random':
                $collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
                break;
            case 'top_rating':
                $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_rating_summary desc');
                break;
            case 'most_reviewed':
                $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_reviews_count desc');
                break;
            case 'most_viewed':
                $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_views_count desc');
                break;
            case 'best_sales':
                $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_ordered_count desc');
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $attribute_to_sort = $cat['0'];         
        switch ($attribute_to_sort){
            case 'name':
            case 'created_at':
            case 'price':
                $collection->addAttributeToSort($attribute_to_sort, $dir);
                break;
            case 'position':
                break;
            case 'random':
                $collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
                break;
            case 'top_rating':
                $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_rating_summary desc');
                break;
            case 'most_reviewed':
                $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_reviews_count desc');
                break;
            case 'most_viewed':
                $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_views_count desc');
                break;
            case 'best_sales':
                $collection->getSelect()->order('sm_ordered_count desc');
                break;
        }   
    }

    if( $is_ajax ){
        $product_limitation = intval(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('ajax_tablisting_start'));
        $collection->getSelect()->limit( $this->_config['product_limitation'], $product_limitation );
    } else {
        $product_limitation = intval($this->_config['product_limitation']);
        if ( $product_limitation > 0 ){
            $collection->setPageSize($product_limitation);
        }
    }
    $maxtitle = $this->getConfig('item_title_max_characs',-1);
    foreach( $collection as $k => $product ) {
        $product_obj = new stdClass();
        $product_obj->id = $product->getId();

        if ( $maxtitle  > 0 ){
            $product_obj->title = Mage::helper('tablisting/data')->truncate($product->getName(), $maxtitle, '');
        } else {
            $product_obj->title = $product->getName();
        }
        $description = $product->getShortDescription();
        if ( (int)$this->getConfig('item_description_striptags') == 1 ){
            $keep_tags = $this->getConfig('item_description_keeptags', '');
            $keep_tags = str_replace(array(' '), array(''), $keep_tags);
            $tmp_desc = strip_tags($description ,$keep_tags );
            $product_obj->description = $tmp_desc;
        } else {
            $product_obj->description = $description;
        }
        if (($maxchars=$this->getConfig('item_desc_max_characs',-1))>0){
            $product_obj->description = Mage::helper('tablisting/data')->truncate($product_obj->description, $maxchars, '');
        }
        $product_obj->image = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize($this->getConfig('item_image_width'), $this->getConfig('item_image_height'));
        $product_obj->link = $product->getProductUrl();
        $product_obj->price_html = $this->getPriceHtml($product, true);
        $product_obj->review_html = $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, 'sm', true);

        $stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
        $stock = $product->getStockItem();
        $status = $stock->getIsInStock();
        if( $stocklevel > 0 && $status == '1' ){
            $items[$product_obj->id] = $product_obj;
        }                       
        //$items[$product_obj->id] = $product_obj;
    }
    return $items;
}   

public function getScriptTags(){
    $import_str = "";
    $jsHelper = Mage::helper('core/js');
    if (null == Mage::registry('jsmart.jquery')){
        // jquery has not added yet
        if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('tablisting_cfg/advanced/include_jquery')){
            // if module allowed jquery.
            $import_str .= $jsHelper->includeSkinScript('sm/tablisting/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js');
            Mage::register('jsmart.jquery', 1);
        }
    }
    if (null == Mage::registry('jsmart.jquerynoconfict')){
        // add once noConflict
        $import_str .= $jsHelper->includeSkinScript('sm/tablisting/js/jquery-noconflict.js');
        Mage::register('jsmart.jquerynoconfict', 1);
    }

    if (null == Mage::registry('jsmart.tablisting.js')){
        // add script for this module.
        //$import_str .= $jsHelper->includeSkinScript('sm/tablisting/js/jquery.isotope.js');
        //Mage::register('jsmart.tablisting.js', 1);
    }
    return $import_str;
}

private function _addCategoryFilter(& $collection, $category_ids){
    $category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    $category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $category_collection->addIsActiveFilter();
    if (count($category_ids)>0){
        $category_collection->addIdFilter($category_ids);
    }

    if (!Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) { 
        $category_collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
    }

    //$category_collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
    $category_products = array();
    foreach ($category_collection as $category){
        $cid = $category->getId();
        if (!array_key_exists( $cid, $category_products)){
            $category_products[$cid] = $category->getProductCollection()->getAllIds();
            //Mage::log("ID: " . $cid );
            //Mage::log("collection->count(): " . count($category_products[$cid]) );
        }
    }
    $product_ids = array();
    if (count($category_products)){
        foreach ($category_products as $cp) {
            $product_ids = array_merge($product_ids, $cp);
        }
    }
    //Mage::log("merged_count: " . count($product_ids));
    $collection->addIdFilter($product_ids);
}

/*private function _addCategoryFilter(& $collection, $category_ids){
    $category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    $category_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $category_collection->addIsActiveFilter();
    $product_ids = array();

    if (count($category_ids)>0){
        $category_collection->addIdFilter($category_ids);
    }

    if (!Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) { 
        $category_collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
    }

    $category_products = array();
    foreach ($category_collection as $category){
        $cid = $category->getId();
        if (!array_key_exists( $cid, $category_products)){
            $category_products[$cid] = $category->getProductCollection()->getAllIds();
        //Mage::log("ID: " . $cid );
        //Mage::log("collection->count(): " . count($category_products[$cid]) );
        }   
    }   
}*/ 

private function _addViewsCount(& $collection, $views_count_alias="sm_views_count"){
    // add views_count
    $reports_event_table        = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('reports/event');
    $reports_event_types_table  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('reports/event_type');
    $collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array("re_table" => $reports_event_table),
        "e.entity_id = re_table.object_id",
        array(
            $views_count_alias => "COUNT(re_table.event_id)"
        )
    )->joinLeft(
        array("ret_table" => $reports_event_types_table),
        "re_table.event_type_id = ret_table.event_type_id AND ret_table.event_name = 'catalog_product_view'",
        array()
    )->group('e.entity_id');
}
private function _addReviewsCount(& $collection, $reviews_count_alias="sm_reviews_count", $rating_summary_alias="sm_rating_summary" ){
    // add reviews_count and rating_summary
    $review_summary_table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('review/review_aggregate');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array("rs_table" => $review_summary_table),
        "e.entity_id = rs_table.entity_pk_value AND rs_table.store_id=" . $this->getStoreId(),
        array(
            $reviews_count_alias  => "rs_table.reviews_count",
            $rating_summary_alias => "rs_table.rating_summary"
        )
    );
}
private function _addOrderedCount(& $collection, $ordered_qty_alias="sm_ordered_count"){
    $order_table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order');
    $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection ('core_read');
    $orders_active_query = $read->select()->from(array("o_table"=>$order_table), 'o_table.entity_id')->where("o_table.state<>'" . Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED . "'");

    $order_item_table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_item');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array("oi_table" => $order_item_table),
        "e.entity_id=oi_table.item_id AND oi_table.order_id IN ($orders_active_query)",
        array(
            $ordered_qty_alias => "SUM(oi_table.qty_ordered)"
        )
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Did you make sure that "Configuration > Inventory > Display out of stock products > Yes" was done at the website and or store view as well (or that the "Use Default" box is checked)?

Comment: Let's get this straight, you're using a module that messes with stock, having problems displaying stock, probably have a custom theme, but you're blaming the core of Magento, which thousands of enterprise sites run on for the issue. Please post code/examples of the problem. Post relevant code of the SM module, etc.

Comment: @Nick M I've updated my message with the code. And anyway this is not my own website in fact you can't imagine how much I hate Magento.

Comment: @user1274113 I definitely understand the frustration, but Magento is a robust solid framework that goes to great lengths to make sure your site doesn't explode errors in a production environment. A downside to this is for developers, you gotta know your way around it and it's log files. Can you post the code in the file `/app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/catalog/product/grid.phtml` for me? Thanks! I'll try to help :)

Comment: Sorry `list.phtml` not `grid.phtml` - long day!

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you should go to `System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog` and set `Use Flat Catalog Product` to `Yes`

Reindex and Flush cache